# How to do division in SQL query between two column

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
In the above image I have 4 column and I am trying to get the average value of criticality and Priority by dividing it by the totalNumber. But for some reason my query is not working and I also trying to just get one decimal place after the division.

My sql query:

```
$command1 = "UPDATE rating SET criticality = criticality + '$c' / totalNumber , Priority = Priority + '$p' / totalNumber, totalNumber = totalNumber + '$counter' WHERE no = '$id'";
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: If you got an error, say about the error message also.

Comment: Please check the updated question. Thank you. and I don't have any error the output of the above query is shown in the image attached

Comment: Try this `criticality = criticality + '$c', criticality = criticality / totalNumber` instead of the original `criticality = criticality + '$c' / totalNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `cast(round(criticality/totalNumber,1) as numeric(36,1))` for one decimal place after division.

```
$command1 = "UPDATE rating SET criticality = cast(round(criticality/totalNumber,1) as numeric(36,1)) , Priority = cast(round(Priority /totalNumber,1) as numeric(36,1)) , totalNumber = totalNumber + '$counter' WHERE no = '$id'";
```

Comment: for some reason your code is not working. But thank you for replying.

Comment: There is no error the as the query is not updating any row in my table